# How to get options data with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape data from option contract pages on Yahoo Finance using BS4. Below is my testing link and the code I wrote to get the info I want.

```py
def get_option_volume(url):
   response = requests.get(url)
   soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
   value = soup.findAll(attrs={"data-reactid":"84"})
   for i in value:
       print(i)

get_option_volume("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL200221C00320000?p=AAPL200221C00320000")
```

When I look at the HTML data for the page I see that the data I want has a tag with attribute datareact-id=84 ...

[image]

but when I run the code, I get values is an empty variable. Where am I going wrong? I looked at documentation and other stackoverflow posts but cannot figure out where my program fails. It works for other random websites but not this one.

Comment: The specific element may have been generated by JavaScript, and that the contents at the provided URL does not have that exact content as your screenshot.

Comment: You don't need to scrape the data, you can use this url:  https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/options/<symbol>?date=<expiration_date>.  Just modify the symbol and expiration date (which should be a timestamp).  Alternatively, you can use a python package called [yahooquery](https://github.com/dpguthrie/yahooquery).  You can retrieve all option chain data through `Ticker('ticker').option_chain`